# Stop raspberry pi rc.local executing

Tags: raspbian, linux

I've added a security python script to the rc.local which unfortunately has a bug - This causes the pi to shut down on start up. Is there a way to bypass this script on start, or boot the pi into an alternative mode?

FYI : I don't have an alternative unix OS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you hold down the shift key while booting, you should end up in a safe mode (minimal Linux install). You can then edit your rc.local file and reboot normally.

A second alternative would be to load a Ubuntu Live CD on your windows machine and then edit the file on the SD card from the running Linux system.

Comment: Sweet I'll give this a crack :)

Comment: How do you edit the rc.local via the linux boot options screen? I can only see the config.txt and cmdline.txt files

Comment: @LukeTesta which method are you using? Can you cd to /etc? Also this may help https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=41686&p=338064

Comment: It's okay I disabled the rc.local script in the cmd config :) Thanks for pointing me towards that menu!

Comment: Which Shift key? Or which version of Raspbian?

Comment: @ThomasWeller I don't know which version of Raspbian was the first to support this but as this question is over a year old anything in that time frame should work. I don't know that it matters which shift key you use pick the one that is most convenient - if it does not work try the other one.

Comment: You could try both at the same time as long as you are not driving.

Comment: Both are not working on Jessie for me